# Xcode "Add Copy Files" build phase fails to copy header files when building universal framework

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, build-automation, universal

I'm trying to create a universal framework for iOS and I have "Add Copy Files" build phase in my aggregate target which tends to behave unexpected (copy some of the files at target location), can you tell me if this can be resolved somehow?

I have added 3 files in this copy build phase...
[image]

After the build is done, this is what I see build log..
[image]

The result is not consistent - sometimes all (3) files get copied but most times it copies only few files to the target location. The build log doesn't give any error/warning for this (copy) phase.

Most probably it's an issue with Xcode. Any workaround/idea to get around this problem is highly appreciated since i need to build the project multiple times in a day (to save time).

---

**Updates/Edits**

If I don't edit any of 3 header files added (+) in 'add copy files' after last build then none of the files is copied inside framework folder on build (cmd+B).

Below are the scripts used in targeted build phases-

Script 1: **Build static lib**

```
xcodebuild -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -sdk iphonesimulator -target ${PROJECT_NAME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator

xcodebuild -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -sdk iphoneos -target ${PROJECT_NAME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos
```

Script 2: **Build universal framework**

```
SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" &&
DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" &&
UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal" &&
UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_PATH="${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}" &&
FRAMEWORK="${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework" &&

# Create framework directory structure.
rm -rf "${FRAMEWORK}" &&
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}" &&
mkdir -p "${FRAMEWORK}/Versions/A/Headers" &&
mkdir -p "${FRAMEWORK}/Versions/A/Resources" &&

# Generate universal binary for the device and simulator.
lipo "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}" "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}" -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_PATH}" &&

# Move files to appropriate locations in framework paths.
cp "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_PATH}" "${FRAMEWORK}/Versions/A" &&
ln -s "A" "${FRAMEWORK}/Versions/Current" &&
ln -s "Versions/Current/Headers" "${FRAMEWORK}/Headers" &&
ln -s "Versions/Current/Resources" "${FRAMEWORK}/Resources" &&
ln -s "Versions/Current/${PRODUCT_NAME}" "${FRAMEWORK}/${PRODUCT_NAME}"
```

I seriously need to fix the underlying real issue to automate the build (avoid workarounds mentioned in my answer). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found that one of the workaround is - just open and save all the files you included in the copy build phase and then build (Cmd+B). (just make the file dirty by adding a space so that modified date is updated)

Comment: **Another workaround:** Building the project _twice_ (i.e. consecutive Cmd+B) ensures the header files specified in 'add copy phase' are copied to absolute path.

Comment: This workaround isn't working for me with Xcode 8.3.3.